# How to workaround: No source is available for type did you forget to inherit a required module?

Tags: java, gwt

In *shared* package i have a class that only uses a class from *server* package, only when it is on server, it is indepdendant of the GWT, and i have made it transient

```
if (!GWT.isClient())
    ServerLogger loggerServer;
```

but it does not compile because it is in shared.. Can i worourund in here?, I just want for the GoogleCompile to work, it should not have the  functionality of the server logger. 
Is there a workaround?

How to write my own module which is NULL overall, because i only want to stop the compiler of erroring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GWT is still trying to compile this code. You will want to use [Deferred Binding](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html) and [`<super-source>`](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html) to swap in the implementation you need at compile-time, so that GWT doesn't try to compile this server-specific code.

Either that, or have the `ServerLogger` implementation be an interface dependency on this shared class, and pass in the correct implementation in server/client:

```
// in your shared package

public class SharedClass {
  private final LoggingClass logging;
  public SharedClass(LoggingClass logging) {
    this.logging = logging;
  }

  public void log(String msg) {
    logging.log(msg);
  }
}

public interface LoggingClass {
  public void log(String msg);
}

// in your client package

public class ClientLogging implements LoggingClass {
  public void log(String msg) { GWT.log(msg); }
}

// in your server package

public class ServerLogging implements LoggingClass {
  public void log(String msg) { ServerLogger.log(msg); }
}
```